# How can I find the list of selectable values in a picker wheel, when using Appium, iOS, and Python?

Tags: python, ios, appium, datetimepicker, picker

I am using Appium and Python to automate a real iOS device. I'd like to know how to obtain a list of the selectable values in a given picker wheel, or at least the size of that list.

I have tried something like this:

```
picker = self.driver.find_element_by_accessibility_id(elem_name)
wheels = picker.find_elements_by_class_name("XCUIElementTypePickerWheel")
```

This gets me a list of all picker wheels. But then I try and find the values of an individual picker wheel like so:

```
list = wheels[1].get_attribute("values")
```

This produces "WebDriverException: Message: The attribute 'values' is unknown."

I have tried other things as well, such as:

```
wheels[1].length
wheels[1].size
```

etc.

So far I haven't been able to figure it out. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Did you get any solutions, I am also facing same issue.